# Dark activated circuit to energize relay gives insufficient current

Tags: current, relay

Dark activated circuit to energize relay - used a 3 V source and a 330 Ω resistor instead of the 470 Ω and used the same circuit.

When I replace the 330 Ω resistor and LED with a 3 V relay it does not draw enough current to operate. Reducing the 100 kΩ resistance has no effect. Increasing input voltage from 3 to 5 V has no effect. How shall I fix this problem?
[image]

Comment: How much current does the 3V relay need? Is that a 9V block battery such as one used on fire alarms and toy remotes?

Comment: You might try an additional BC547 in a darlington like connection to achieve enough current to drive the relay.

Comment: What’s the battery voltage under load?

Comment: The batteries are 2 AAs. I don't know thecurrent required for the relay coil?

Comment: "You might try an additional BC547 in a darlington like connection " -  I'm not sure about that circuit - would you show me a schematic? Thx

Comment: Below is a link to an article on the Darlington pair configuration.  Unfortunately the BC547 may have another limitation, the max continuous IC is only 100mA.  So unless you have a very low power relay that transistor may not be sufficient.  You need to find the specifications of your relay to properly select a transistor and drive circuitry.  Darlington info:https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/darlington-pair

Comment: thx. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Favorite link [Darlington Transistors](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/darlington-transistor.html) (see the whole 11 sections on transistors)

Comment: Schematic says 9 V. Please edit.